# Assign lables for previous n days based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Hi i have problem with calculating/labelling the dates previous 11 days (irrespective of repeated or missing).
I need to assaign lables in "Day_mark" column for previous 11 days(or n days dynamically) lables when i found '1' in column 'day'
Below is my dataset and required column is 'Day_mark'

for ex: in row 18 i found '1' and need to assaign previous 11 days lables.
in row 27 i found '1' and nee to assign previous 11 days lables but we do not have 11 days so limited to day-7

```
data = {'Date':['2021-10-4','2021-10-7','2021-10-9','2021-10-10','2021-10-11','2021-10-11','2021-10-12',
                '2021-10-12','2021-10-13','2021-10-14','2021-10-15','2021-10-15','2021-10-16','2021-10-16',
                '2021-10-17','2021-10-18','2021-10-19','2021-10-20','2021-10-21','2021-11-1','2021-11-2',
                '2021-11-3','2021-11-3','2021-11-3','2021-11-5','2021-11-6','2021-11-7','2021-11-8','2021-11-9'],
           'Hour':[ 9,11,12,13,5,7,2,20,21,23,1,2,5,7,15,16,17,1,12,13,5,7,2,20,21,23,16,17,13],
'Mark':[ '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',1,'','','','','','','','',1,'',''],
'Day_mark':['','','d11','d10','d9','d9','d8','d8','d7','d6','d5','d5','d4','d4','d3','d2','d1','d7',
            'd6','d5','d4','d3','d3','d3','d2','d1',' ',' ',' ']
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've shown your data but seem to have forgotten to show your code and expected output

Comment: Thanks @jcaesar,Expected output column is 'Day_mark

Comment: The Day_mark values have been populated so what's your problem?

Comment: To understand the viewers i have populated the column 'Day_mark' , but it is actually a required column/output column

Comment: Please show the code you've used to populate Day_mark and explain the logic behind the d1, d2 etc values. Also, whilst it is likely to work, it seems odd that you're mixing strings and integers in 'Mark'. Why is that? Are the 'Hour' values relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create groups column by shift mask with compare `1`, change order by `iloc` and add cumulative sum and then remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then use [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) and set empty string if no match between `1,11` with remove last rows after last `1`:

```
df['g'] = df['Mark'].eq(1).shift(-1).iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]

df['new'] = df.drop_duplicates('Date').groupby('g').cumcount(ascending=False).add(1)

s = df.groupby('g')['new'].ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
df['new'] = np.where(df['g'].gt(0) & s.between(1,11), 'd' + s.astype(str), '')
df = df.drop('g', axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
          Date  Hour Mark Day_mark  new
0    2021-10-4     9                   
1    2021-10-7    11                   
2    2021-10-9    12           d11  d11
3   2021-10-10    13           d10  d10
4   2021-10-11     5            d9   d9
5   2021-10-11     7            d9   d9
6   2021-10-12     2            d8   d8
7   2021-10-12    20            d8   d8
8   2021-10-13    21            d7   d7
9   2021-10-14    23            d6   d6
10  2021-10-15     1            d5   d5
11  2021-10-15     2            d5   d5
12  2021-10-16     5            d4   d4
13  2021-10-16     7            d4   d4
14  2021-10-17    15            d3   d3
15  2021-10-18    16            d2   d2
16  2021-10-19    17            d1   d1
17  2021-10-20     1    1       d7   d7
18  2021-10-21    12            d6   d6
19   2021-11-1    13            d5   d5
20   2021-11-2     5            d4   d4
21   2021-11-3     7            d3   d3
22   2021-11-3     2            d3   d3
23   2021-11-3    20            d3   d3
24   2021-11-5    21            d2   d2
25   2021-11-6    23            d1   d1
26   2021-11-7    16    1              
27   2021-11-8    17                   
28   2021-11-9    13
```

---

Another dea is compare last date per groups and subtract, but output is different:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['g'] = df['Mark'].eq(1).shift(-1).iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]

df['new'] = (df.groupby('g')['Date']
               .transform('last')
               .sub(df['Date'])
               .dt.days
               .add(1)
               .fillna(0)
               .astype(int))

df['new'] = np.where(df['g'].gt(0) & df['new'].le(11), 'd' + df['new'].astype(str), '')
df = df.drop('g', axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
         Date  Hour Mark Day_mark  new
0  2021-10-04     9                   
1  2021-10-07    11                   
2  2021-10-09    12           d11  d11
3  2021-10-10    13           d10  d10
4  2021-10-11     5            d9   d9
5  2021-10-11     7            d9   d9
6  2021-10-12     2            d8   d8
7  2021-10-12    20            d8   d8
8  2021-10-13    21            d7   d7
9  2021-10-14    23            d6   d6
10 2021-10-15     1            d5   d5
11 2021-10-15     2            d5   d5
12 2021-10-16     5            d4   d4
13 2021-10-16     7            d4   d4
14 2021-10-17    15            d3   d3
15 2021-10-18    16            d2   d2
16 2021-10-19    17            d1   d1
17 2021-10-20     1    1       d7     
18 2021-10-21    12            d6     
19 2021-11-01    13            d5   d6
20 2021-11-02     5            d4   d5
21 2021-11-03     7            d3   d4
22 2021-11-03     2            d3   d4
23 2021-11-03    20            d3   d4
24 2021-11-05    21            d2   d2
25 2021-11-06    23            d1   d1
26 2021-11-07    16    1              
27 2021-11-08    17                   
28 2021-11-09    13
```